# New module does not appear on Live

Tags: magento-1.9

I've installed a custom module on our dev server which worked fine.  I've the used git to move it to the production site.  I can see the module listed under "Advanced" and I can see the code is there, but it is not working.  It should display a new attribute under categories, but it is now.  I have reindexed & cleared cache.

Any thoughs?

Comment: Please check your module's entry under **`core_resource`** table. I think there is version mismatch in the config.xml file and the module version in the table.

Comment: There can be one more problem that the setup script written in the sql folder is incomplete. Please match it with some reputed tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the above comments.  It was due to version number.  I incremented it and this solved the problem.